# Why does indexPath.row start at 1 instead of 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView in a scrollView that grows itself everytime a new value is added to it because of the below function

```
class IntrinsicPostTableView: UITableView {

    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    self.heightConstraint?.constant = self.tableView.intrinsicContentSize.height
}
```

but this causes cellForRowAt to fire twice,if my list has 3 items indexPath.row returns as 0 1 2  the first time, the second time it returns as 1 2. Any solutions to help with this problem would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to design a code which assumes that numberOfSections, numberOfRows or cellForIndexPath of UITableView will be called in a non ordered and non exhaustive list of cells.

In you case you had also a problem with a cell were reused and had images which were updated according to a cell model. In case of reusing a cell it is necessary to set images, assets or others elements to initial values in prepareForReuse method of UITableViewCell

Comment: I have another problem that occurs and i suspect its because of indexPath.row, so the goal is to get 012 instead of 01212

Comment: UITableView can call cellForRowAt as needed. You should not expect that indexPath in this method will be in any order or range

Comment: cellForRowAt can be called multiple times and for indexPath which will be important from the point of view of UITableView

Comment: Also methods like numberOfSections or Rows will be called multiple times in a difficult to predict timing

Comment: basically my issue is that I have a likes function that needs to check if the user has already liked the post everytime the tableView is relaoded and i have a pretty large tableView, something like instagram, which messes up the liking sometimes, so i might have one cell liked but another cell will display the appropriate UI changes, other times the id of the class in each cell won't pass over correctly and it would cause the liking to mess up

Comment: It looks like you have cells which were dequeued (reused) and have already state which was defined in previous call cellForIndexPath. If this is the problem then instead let cell. = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "") use let cell = UITableViewCell(). Other solution is to have a custom cell subclass with prepareForReuse method which will clear a cell before configuring it with a model data

Comment: But what if i need variables from the tableViewCell?

Comment: in case of creating a dedicated subclass of UITableViewCell you already have a typed cell so this is not a problem. In case of dequeue you have to cast it with as! or as? operator

Comment: Also adding super.viewLayoutSubviews causes indexPath.row to fire 12 instead of 01212

Comment: As I said don't expect that cellForIndexPath will be called for all cells and in a ordered way. It's safer to think that cellForIndexPath can be called randomly

Comment: when i cast it with as! i get the message "Cast from 'UITableViewCell.Type' to unrelated type 'PostCell' always fails", i also get SIGABRT when i run it

Comment: So maybe your cell in Interface Builder has no subclass associated to it

Comment: it does though, i just checked as well

Comment: Sure thing, what code snippets would you be interested in? I can't dm you as i only have one rep but ill add them to the post

Comment: Thank you so much for the zoom call, u solved my problem